# External javascript file is not loading in IE Developer/FireBug/Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging

External java script file is not getting displayed in debugger tools (IE/Mozilla/Chrome). But the script is working. I need to debug it, I found a lot of thread regarding the same issue. but all resolved because of some syntax error or putting a debugger; keyword. But nothing is working out here.. Script is executing perfectly and its downloading to Temporary Internet Files

//Sake of simplifying my problem just reduced the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
debugger;
alert($('.providermodallink').length); // alert is displayed while loading 
$('.providential').click(function(event){
 debugger;
 alert('hello world');
});
})
```

above java script file is rendered as a script block with an integer name in IE like script block(9), any body know the reason ?...

Comment: provide a jsfiddle sample, to help us figure out the problem.

Comment: Do you have the developer tools pane open in Chrome while loading your page?  The `debugger;` instruction only does something when the debugger is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Application is a legacy one (too complicated) and we are providing some enhancement, so the hosting control where I referenced the script was loading **multiple times** somewhere in the application,

So that makes the debugger tools life complicated